# Angular 15 mat-table refresh after user inputs data for a new column

Tags: angular, datasource, angular-material-table

I have an angular 15 WebApp. In one of my components theres a mat-table. It displays activityEntries, which is an Array of Obejcts (activity: Interface). I can display it easily with the columns i´d like.
But it doesn´t update. The user can provide new activityEntries via a Dialog from another component. I can fetch these data and update the acitvityEntries. But the mat-table does not.

I dont want to store these data in a Database an access it over an API. I want to collect these activityEntries and maybe save them in the sessionStorage. First, if i have enough entries, i send them to an API as a Collection.

I tried the following solutions i already found:

1. this.table.renderRows(); || + || @ViewChild(MatTable) table!: MatTable;
   Even if i name the mat-table #activtiyTable, it is always undefined.
2. this.changeDetection.detectChanges() || doesnt do anything
3. this.datasource.data = this.datasoruce.data || this.datasource.data = [...this.datasoruce.data]
4. Making this.datasoruce a behavioral subject.

Non of these work for me. I guess they're not compatible with angular 15.

Comment: how and when do you update the acitvityEntries (use console.log(this.activityEntries) to see if it's updated)? If you use `@ViewChild(MatTable) recallTable!: MatTable`, remember that when you make `this.recallTable.renderRows();` (see that it's recallTable) the table should be "disposible" (painted in the screen)

Comment: Yes i see, that the correct table is recognized by WebStrom. By the way its "activityTable". Sorry i´ll edit this. I update this.activityEntries like this:

dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(result => {
      if (result) {
        this.addActivityEntry(result);
      }
    });

Then in addActivityEntries: 

this.activityEntries.push(entry);
Even with behavioral this.activitSubject.next(entry) it does not work.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

try (check before if success)

```
addActivityEntries(entry:any){
 this.activityEntries.push(entry); //<--add the data
 this.dataSource.data=this.activityEntries;  //<--equal the dataSource.data
 this.table.renderRows()   //<--render the table
}
```

**Update** about ViewChild

When we use ViewChild we can use

```
@ViewChild(MatTable) table!: MatTable
//or is we use a template reference variable(1)
@ViewChild('activityTable') table!: MatTable
```

The "variable" is in both cases "table", so,

1. inside the .ts we use `this.table`
2. inside the .html we can use `activityTable` better than `table`

(1)[template reference variable](https://angular.io/guide/template-reference-variables)

Comment: Does not work!

My table:     <table #activityTable mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" class="mat-elevation-z8">

Console says: this.activityTable is not defined. But its in the html of the same component and IDE recognizes it.

Comment: @user15822971, the "variable" should be "table" (I update the answer about ViewChild)

Comment: I changed the variable. It still says that this.table is undefined at the point where i call "this.table.renderRows()". Should i instantiate the table anywhere?

Comment: when you call to this.table.renderRows(), the table is visible?. If the table is under a *ngIf you need remember two things: **not** use `{static:true}` in ViewChild, and remember that you only can call to a function if the table is visible. Sometime you need enclosed the instruction in a `setTimeout(()=>{..your instruction..})`

Comment: The table is visible. I can see the header all of the time. When i load an array into the datasource, its values fill the table correctly. When i update the array nothing happens with the table. But the console logs the correct new array. I don´t use static with the viewchild and i don´t understand your second suggestion. Could you explain it further?

Comment: the last one it's only if you don't see the table. e.g. if is under a `*ngIf="variable"` you use: `variable=true;setTimeout(()=>{console.log(this.table)}`, to give time to Angular, first to paint the table, and after Angular can "reach" the table. But this is not your case. I really don't know what happens, sorry.

Comment: I´m trying to do it just like in this example here: https://material.angular.io/components/table/examples  Table Nr.3. And console always shows me the correct Array but, this.table seems to be undefined.

Comment: Could this happen, because of the Version? I tried 15 and 16 so far. This Guy talks about "Classic-Change-Detection" vs Signals (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qalOpo6Mc-8), which seem to be a new feature of 16. But idk if 15 already, too. As you are more familiar to angular, could you recommend me a stable version of angular that i should use, or is the newest always the best. I read a lot about older features and releases, but not having them used makes me still undecided, which one to use.

Comment: Update: If found out, that removing an Object from the Array works and the table refreshes correctly. So i guess the adding of ArrayEntires is wrong. I gather those Objects from a UserMatDialog. They look the same, but anywhere they might differ.